# Fill a rectangle with polyominos

Tags: algorithm

Recently I've been playing a game which had a puzzle in it, like in the picture. In this puzzle you have to fill the board with polyominos. I thought about writing a program which could solve this and came up with a general recursion, which iterates through all possible placements of the objects, but it fails with larger boards (say 10x10 with 20 objects). I wonder if there is any optimal algorithm for solving such problems.

[image: puzzle]

Comment: Start [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/271634/Puzzle-Solver)